# How to load video driver after boot up with nomodeset?

Tags: drivers, graphics, nomodeset

Is there any chance to properly load graphics driver after booting with nomodeset option in GRUB? System freezes on boot without nomodeset.

inxi -G
Graphics:
Device-1: AMD RV530/M56-P [Mobility Radeon X1600] driver: N/A
Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev FAILED: ati
unloaded: modesetting,radeon,vesa resolution: 1680x1050~77Hz
OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3

uname -a
Linux 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Loading the driver afterwards wont fix the freezing during boot :)  Is that a MacBookPro2 perhaps?  If so it is likely not going to work.  Here is a list https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:1002-71c5-106b-0080 of models.

Comment: Thanks. I've read it's possible. But don't know, how to accomplish it. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/radeon-driver-for-linux-on-2006-macbook-pro.2206534/post-27895047